# How to create a list of class heirs? Java

Tags: java, generics, collections

guys. My question is simple. Can you help me what I do incorrect?
I am trying to code smth like this, but got an error of compilation.

```
List<? extends Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<BaseIRPMException>();
exceptions.add(new BaseException("Some text ");
```

Comment: Note that `List<? extends Exception> exceptions` can hold also something like `new ArrayList<NullPointerException>()`. In that case should `exceptions.add(new BaseException("Some text ");` compile fine?

Comment: How exactly are the classes `BaseIRPMException` and `BaseException` defined? What is their inheritance relationship? Do you have any JavaDoc for them?

Comment: In addition, it is worth noting that you can add a `BaseException` (or any subclass) to a regular `List<Exception>`. Maybe that helps already.

Comment: I mean the simplest situation. Let us call it
`List<? extends Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();`
`exceptions.add(new BaseException("Some text "); `

Comment: Lets rewrite your code a little. Should such code compile `public static void foo(List<? extends Exception> exceptions){ exceptions.add(new BaseException("Some text ")); }` ? Note that can be invoked with `foo(new ArrayList<BaseIRPMException>());` but also `foo(new List<NullPointerException>());`.

Comment: Also note that your example needs additional `)` at `exceptions.add(new BaseException("Some text ");` (before `;`)

Answer (score 1):

`List<? extends Exception>` means you have a `List` of some kind of exceptions but you don't know what kind of exceptions.

Because you don't know what kind of exceptions you need to insert, you cannot pass some special kind of exception to the list.

A `List<? extends Exception>` could be a `List<IllegalArgumentException>` and you cannot add a `NullPointerException` to such a list.

However, you can retrieve `Exception`s from such a list.

As the compiler knows that your `List` contains some kind of `Exception`, elements, you can call `.get()` and assign the returned value to a variable of type `Exception` but you cannot assign it to a subtype because the compiler doesn't know the actual subtype.

If you want to create a list of subtypes of exceptions, you might want to use a `List<Exception>` as it also allows subtypes.

Comment: In almost all of these sorts of cases, what the user really wants is just `List<Exception>`, without the generic.s.  Then any sort of Exception can be put in, and Exception can be taken out.  The natural covariance of the class system is usually what people want.